# Echo large ammount of HTML without freeze browser

Tags: php

I'm echoing around five thousand lines in the PHP page, the problem is that it freezes, and it only continues to load the page and the javascript code when all the echoing process is over.
How can I echo without making the page wait the echo process to complete to finish loading the page?
When I echo like <100 lines, it loads fast, so I guess PHP is somehow making everything else wait to finish loading.
**Page:**

```
<table>
   echo $rows;
</table>
```

**$rows value (five thousand rows, each row with the following structure):**

```
<tr>
    <td>EXAMPLE</td>
    <td>EXAMPLE</td>
    <td>EXAMPLE</td>
    <td>EXAMPLE</td>
    <td>EXAMPLE</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The question I have to ask is why are you echoing 5000 rows... I assume it's database information, but why? Also, have you considered filtering the results, pagination, etc?

Comment: The freezing is the browser not able to finish loading the page. You cannot control this with PHP- it's best to only output a set number of fields and utilize pagination/filtering, as @TimLewis said.

Comment: Maybe you could try using an AJAX call to grab the HTML rather than the echo. You do plan to paginate the results, right? You could ask for smaller chunks this way. I mean, there are 5000 rows... if so, that'd be a great approach to take!

Comment: You need to look at using something like [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and AJAX.

Comment: I'm echoing 5000 rows because the company doesn't want pagination, they want to see it all. And I was using AJAX before, it was a little bit faster, but almost the same.

Comment: Tell your company that if they want to see all the information, they should open it up in Phpmyadmin, MySQLWorkbench or some other MySQL reading program, not echo it all to the screen at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the suggestions about various ways of not generating massive tables are completely valid. However, this issue at hand is because the browser cannot render a table until it knows everything in the table *(so it can adjust column widths, etc)*.

If you are set on generating massive tables, the best you can do is optimize the table's display properties. This super old MSDN article contains info on ways to speed up browser rendering of HTML tables: [Building High Performance HTML Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533020%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Essentially, **use fixed sized tables**:

> Tables are a great way of organizing information. Before CSS
> positioning was implemented in Internet Explorer 4.0, many HTML
> authors even used tables to lay out elements on their page. Now, if
> you're still using tables to achieve the latter, you ought to be using
> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) positioning instead. Internet Explorer 5
> offers even better performance to those who have embraced CSS.
>
> Of course that doesn't rule out using tables altogether. Tables still have a place, and when you use them, you should specify the table-layout CSS attribute to achieve optimal performance out of Internet Explorer 5 or later. By doing the following, you'll allow Internet Explorer to start rendering the table before it has received all the data.
>
> - Set the table-layout CSS attribute to fixed on the table.
> - Explicitly define col objects for each column.
> - Set the WIDTH attribute on each col.

Again, this is **REALLY OLD** information, but it is still valid in this case.

Try it out and see if it helps speed up rendering of your gigantic tables.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-sided, it cannot affect your browser. Of course, server can have respond time like 5 minutes, but it never cause browser to freeze. What actually freezes it can be javascript or shockwave flash.

PHP works that way:

1) Parses all php code
2) Create HTML code on server side
3) sends HTTP headers and HTML code to client (browser)

so it will never send anything until it end creating HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, meaning that when you hit your webpage, the PHP executes before anything else. What you could do is integrate some jQuery to load the rows, or perhaps even use an embedded iframe on your page to let the script load before the rows.

jQuery: (untested)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your page!</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadstuff() {
      // Borrowed from: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp
      $.get("get_rows.php",function(name,data){
      $("#table123 tr").append("<td>"+name+" ... "+data+"</td>");
      });
    }
    window.onload = loadstuff;
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Load some stuff</h1>
  <table id="table123">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

iFrame:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your page!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Your Page!</h1>
    <iframe src="www.example.com/slow_loading_rows"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```